# Generate XML from SQL Server using XML explicit and CDATA directive

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I need to generate the XML from the SQL Server 2008 R2 using 'For XML explicit' and CDATA directive. The output should be like following:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<JOB>
<AD>
 <ID><![CDATA[ 451 ]]></ID>
 <TITLE><![CDATA[ Receptionist ]]></TITLE>
</AD>
<AD>
 <ID><![CDATA[ 1025 ]]></ID>
 <TITLE><![CDATA[ Secretary ]]></TITLE>
</AD>
</JOB>
```

While, the schema of table is,

```
Table Name : AD
Column1    : ID
Column2    : TITLE
```

But, I am unable to achieve this and stuck somewhere.

Many thanks.

Comment: This is not valid XML - it is lacking a single root element...

Comment: I include the single root element. Updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @T table(ID int, TITLE varchar(50))
insert into @T values(451, 'Receptionist')
insert into @T values(1025, 'Secretary')

select 1    as Tag,
       null as Parent,
       ID as [AD!1!ID!CDATA],
       TITLE as [AD!1!TITLE!CDATA]
from @T       
order by [AD!1!ID!CDATA]
for xml explicit
```

Result:

```
<AD>
  <ID><![CDATA[451]]></ID>
  <TITLE><![CDATA[Receptionist]]></TITLE>
</AD>
<AD>
  <ID><![CDATA[1025]]></ID>
  <TITLE><![CDATA[Secretary]]></TITLE>
</AD>
```

**Edit:**
With root node:

```
declare @T table(ID int, TITLE varchar(50))
insert into @T values(451, 'Receptionist')
insert into @T values(1025, 'Secretary')

select 1    as Tag,
       null as Parent,
       null as [JOB!1],
       null as [AD!2!ID!CDATA],
       null as [AD!2!TITLE!CDATA]
union all
select 2    as Tag,
       1 as Parent,
       null,
       ID,
       TITLE
from @T 
order by Tag, [AD!2!ID!CDATA]       
for xml explicit
```

Comment: Perfect answer! The inclusion of CDATA was essential for me as I was exporting a table that contained a lot of special characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

about the root node, newer versions of MSSQL allow for writing the easier:

```
FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('***YOURROOTTAGNAME***')
```